# How do I get the same result for xpath1 OR xpath2 in Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

How to get the same result if condition:

```
//div[@class='lng-info']/h5[text() = 'PMP']
```

*or* condition

```
//div[@class='lng-info']/div[@class='price']
```

is true ?

How do I write a single xpath expression that combines the two above xpath and return the same elements while running the code?

Answer (score 1):

Use `|` union operator. Your xpath will be:

```
//div[@class='lng-info']/h5[text() = 'PMP']|//div[@class='lng-info']/div[@class='price']
```

For example:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div id="abc"/>
    </div>
    <test>
        <div id="def"/>
    </test>
</div>
```

xpath `//div/div[@id='abc']|//test/div[@id='def']` will return

```
Element='<div id="abc"/>'
Element='<div id="def"/>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following or preceding Advanced Xpath to combine the two xpath. Try this below code.

```
//div[@class='lng-info']/h5[text() = 'PMP']/following:://div[@class='lng-info']/div[@class='price']

//div[@class='lng-info']/h5[text() = 'PMP']/preceding:://div[@class='lng-info']/div[@class='price']
```

Comment: //div[@class='lng-info']/following::*[1][text() = 'PMP' or @class='price']

Answer (score 0):

We avoid using Xpath in our automation scripts as it is on least priority. In our automation testing company priority we follow is id > class> name> CSS> xpath.

```
//div[@class='lng-info']/h5[text() = 'PMP' OR @class='price']
```

Thanks in advance. Please do reply if it fails to work.